# How to include image, text and button in toolbar?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

In my android app, I wish to build a toolbar like so:

[image]

How can I increase the height of the toolbar and include an image, text and button?

Answer (score 4):

make you toolbar like this

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
     android:id="@+id/toolbar"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
     android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
     app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_error" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Did you know"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/FactTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="demo text" />

         <--> add here more controls<-->

    </LinearLayout>

</Toolbar>
```

Comment: Thank you thats all I wanted!

Comment: @TomFinet if this help you than please accept my ans

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

1. [Collapsible Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html)
2. [Coordinator Layout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html)

Some real examples: 
https://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/
http://tutorialsbuzz.com/2015/11/android-collapsingtoolbarlayout-example_7.html

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <com.antonioleiva.materializeyourapp.SquareImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @NileshRathod - I have done the required changes, request you to kindly remove the down vote.

Comment: i didn't down vote i just suggest you to not give link in ans